Call by value-result
void foo( int x, int y , int z) { 
    int temp = z;
    z = y;
    y=x;
    x = temp;}

void main { 
    int k = 1;
    int j = 3;

    int t[5] = {1,3,2,3,1};
    foo( t[k], t[j] k);
}

In the pseudocode above suppose we call x, y and z by value-result. Inside the function the value of z changes so when the function completes k will have a new value. My question relates to the variable that x will copy out to when the function completes. Will it copy its value to x= t[k=1] which was the variable passed at the start or to the new value of k meaning x=t[k=3] . Does the order of the variables matter? If foo was instead foo(int z,int x,int y) then k would copy out first so x would copy out to the matrix using the new value of k?
I tried to simulate the code in C but since it does not support call by value-result I am not sure about the results.

Please post the code as text and tag your question with the relevant programming language

@MathiasR.Jessen there is not a revelant programming language, it is a pseudocode and  the process refers to  pass by value-result mechanism which does not depend to a specific language
